# axios multipart request failing

Tags: node.js, post, axios, multipartform-data

Im trying to send a post request for convert doc to pdf using a service. The service is working fine with postman, y can send the doc to the endpoint and it return me the pdf, nice.

But i cant make the request from my nodejs server, im using axios to make the request and it fails with this is the error:

```
{"time":"2019-09-24T14:39:46.89404124Z","id":"","remote_ip":"000.00.000.00","host":"pdf-doc-convert.example","method":"POST","uri":"/convert/office","user_agent":"axios/0.19.0","status":500,"error":"getting multipart form: no multipart boundary param in Content-Type","latency":221460,"latency_human":"221.46µs","bytes_in":0,"bytes_out":36}
```

This is the service documentation, is a simple post with a multipart/form-data request (come with a curl example):

https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/#office

And this is my request with axios:

```
async function request() {
    const endpoint =
          "http://pdf-doc-convert.example/convert/office";
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('files', fs.createReadStream("my/file/path/example.docx"));
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };
    const pdf = await axios.post(endpoint, data, config);
}
```

How can i make the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the quickest way to debug this would be to intercept the call you're making with the Axios request using Postman Intercept and to compare the cURL request info from the one that's working to the one that's not. It could be either a headers issue or file encoding issue.

I've encountered something similar previously and this could be related to the formData headers which require additional configuration in Axios as mentioned here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789#issuecomment-508114703

```
const data = new FormData();

data.append("firstFile", fs.createReadStream(firstFilePath), { knownLength: fs.statSync(firstFilePath).size });

const headers = {
    ...data.getHeaders(),
    "Content-Length": data.getLengthSync()
};

const endpoint = "http://pdf-doc-convert.example/convert/office";

const pdf = await axios.post(endpoint, data, config);
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  y add the data.getHeaders()  to my code and it work fine. The config looks like this now const config { headers: data.getHeaders() }.